# Timing code parts in Unix (Ubuntu)?

Tags: visual-c++, ubuntu, time

I am new to using Ubuntu, I wrote a classification algorithm in C++ for windows, in which I had to make a note of the training and the testing time, so I used SYSTEMTIME using the header file windows.h . Now I am trying to run the code in Ubuntu, but windows.h is not recognized, is there a replacement for windows.h header in Ubuntu. If not any suggestions on how should I time the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use struct tm from time.h
For C++ use

```
#include <ctime>
```

The structure is:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```